# mysql loop to display images. Need help to pass/setting count for each image - javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a sql loop that displays images from a database. I then put all the paths of the images in a js array. Which i pass to an onClick function. Which works ok. But my question is can i pass or associate the count value after each iteration of the loop to the corresponding image

ie if i click on the first image "0" get passed to the function so i can use it to get the corrseponding image path from the array.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var pathArray=new Array();
            var count = -1;
        </script>
        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
            ?>  
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    path = '<?php echo $row['path'];?>'; 
                    pathArray.push(path); 
                    count++;    
                </script>  

                <div id="displayimage"><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $row['path'];?>" width="200px" height="156px" style="border:solid 2px white;margin-left:15px;" onclick="openImages(pathArray,count);"></a></div>    

                <?php
                    $i++;
                    if($i % 3 === 0)
                    {
                    echo "<br /><br /><br />";          
                    } 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is put the server-side variable into the call to `openImages`:

```
onclick="openImages(<?php echo $i; ?>);"
```

Then, make the `openImages` function take an integer as the parameter (remove the others, they're not needed):

```
function openImages(i) {
    alert(path[i]);
}
```

---

Alternatively, maybe it would be easier to simply send the path as the parameter?  Then you could remove the script block from the loop entirely.  (That is, assuming you don't have other uses for `pathArray`.)

```
onclick="openImages('<?php echo $row['path']; ?>')"
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfect i had tried your alternative but had for got the single quotes around the php tags.